# Assigning roles in different way

Tags: asp.net

recently i thought to apply roles to users in a different way,without using role manager etc.like create one column named 'ROLES'...and redirect user by checking this column at login time.I know so many of you are thinking what is i am gonna do.I am also thinking the same.I know one drawback of this technique,that is one user cant have multiple roles.Is there any other drawbacks of this technique and why should this technique be avoided and one should use role manager instead of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Rohan, There is nothing wrong with your way. I have used this type of techniques for 2 years because I was too lazy to go thru the role managers and overriding it where needed.

However i feel now that I have always reinvented the wheel. Its your persective how you see that.

and your last question "why should this technique be avoided and one should use role manager instead of this?" the answer is because it is readymade and timetested. Any **new** code that you write has a theoritical limit that it can have bug, so suppose you have rolled out your own authentication engine- you will have to test it.. Isnt it extra efford that you have to put?

Comment: ok i got your point....i just wanted to make sure if there are any other issues.....

Answer (score 0):

Use that [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20211016204853/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050306-1.aspx), I think it will help you..

Comment: :I am not asking about how to trace invalid logins or to maintain the report for the same.i am asking that i have found another way to implement the roles...i just want to know what is wrong with that?why should i go through role manager and all that things whereas i have the simple solution as i have described above...?